# JSF: Javascript in Ajax JSF-response

Tags: ajax, jsf-2

I'd like to execute Javascript after an Ajax-request in JSF? I can execute Javascript with the onevent listener, but the code I want to execute should be sent in the Ajax-response.

But apparently, JSF strips out script tags in the Ajax response. So what's the official way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

To execute js on every ajax request use Omnifaces `onloadScript` component:

[Omnifaces onloadScript showcase](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/components/onloadScript)